# Sorting columns of a table in Tableau

Tags: sorting, tableau-api, columnsorting

I am looking to sort the following table in Tableau by risk rating and date. For risk rating in can bethe form of Low-Medium-High or the other way round and for the date it is from earliest to latest and the other way round. I understand that Tableau does some kind of nesting from left to right such that it only sorts the leftmost column. How can I overcome that such that a user can do a sort with as little effort as possible (perhaps in the form of a button?)

[image]

Comment: What is the desired output in this case?

Comment: sorting in the dashboard by risk rating and date

Comment: 1) low- medium -high
2) high - medium -low 
3) oldest -newest
4)  newest - oldest

Comment: That I understand, but I need to see the output format

Comment: just a dropdown function on the table to initiate the sorting

Comment: Something which may seem obvious to you, as you know your problem best, may not be as obvious to others.  It is therefore requested to please generate a simple output as you are seeing (because the data format you have shared is already sorted for me and I am not able to perceive how do you want to see it) and share it in your question